# Why is there a Python iteration problem in a class

Tags: python, class, iterator

I ran code like this:

```
class MyNumber:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.it=1
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        b=self.it
        self.b+=1
        return b


num=MyNumber()
it=iter(num)
print(next(it))
```

There is an error:

```
  File "test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(next(it))
  File "test2.py", line 8, in __next__
    self.b+=1
AttributeError: 'MyNumber' object has no attribute 'b'
```

I ran it with the shell in Replit,python3.
Please check it for me.

Comment: You want `self.it += 1`; `b` simply saves the value of `self.it` before you increment it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: That's the suggestion; `self.b` doesn't exist and isn't the attribute you want to increment; `self.it` is.

Comment: @metatoaster Initializing the attribute in `__iter__` lets you iterate over the item more than once (although it doesn't allow multiple *concurrent* iterators).

Comment: You should initialize the initial value via `__init__`, and `__iter__` should simply `return self`. When `next(it)` is called, it does not invoke `__iter__` at all, next assumed that the argument passed already an iterator, thus it's identical to calling `it.__next__()`

Comment: @chepner not a good pattern, in which case it should return a new instance of the iterator if restart is to be supported.  Python iterators are not designed to be reused, and any attempt to design something to permit that may introduce unwanted behaviors.

Comment: It may not be a great pattern, but it at least *allows* multiple repetition. Setting `self.itr = 1` only in `__init__` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably either mean

```
    def __next__(self):
        b=self.it
        b+=1
        return b
```

or

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.b=self.it
        self.b+=1
        return self.b
```

(As noted in the comments above, this probably is not going to do what you think it's going to do, but that's a separate problem from your error message.)